# Change legend title "mesh3d" object in plotly R

Tags: r, plotly, legend

I am using the following code to generate a 3d plot with plotly in R. The variables mapped to the x, y and z axes are probabilities and some of the combinations are evaluated. Eventually, I have mapped the variable RE as the intensity variable. However, when generating the plot, the legend title for intensity has as title 'p3' and not 'RE' as it should be. I have tried setting `name = "RE"` inside the `add_trace()` function but this doesn't change anything. Does somebody know an alternative to change the legend title to "RE"? I have also attached a copy of the plot.

```
library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly() %>% add_trace(data = re_data,  x=~p1, y=~p2, z=~p3, type="mesh3d",
      intensity = ~r.eff , text = ~paste('</br> p1:', p1,
      '</br> p2:', p2,
      '</br> p3:', p3,
      '</br> RE: ', r.eff), 
      hoverinfo = "text" ,colors=c("cyan","darkblue"))
```

[image: Plot]